Transaction roll back not happening in case of multi threading even if @Transactional is used
We have a method to write data into multiple tables and to make it faster its been set to run in multi threading using Completeble Future concepts. This method is wrapped using Spring @Transactional and for roollback proper excpetion been thrown.
Now the issue is differenet threads are responsible for saving data into different tables in parallel. Howver if any exception occurs, its rolling back only for the method where its running and other methods are not getting rolled back which are running in a different thread.
We are using Spring MVC and jdbctemplate is used to do all DB operations
Can you please help to advise what is the approach to handle transaction in a multi threaded envviorment in spring. Thanks for your sugeestion in advance.

Can you provide code you have used?
